# Loop thru DAO Recordset to join my table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, dao

I have VBA in access to loop through  my table 2 recordset and join each row with my main table and create new worksheet.
I'm pretty new and can't figure out the problem; and ? This time run-time error 3296 JOIN expression not supported can you experts look through my code and help me?

Here is My [sampleDB] https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B980etBxqQuzTGxiS1g3eUlLcHc/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you.

```
 Sub ExportReport()

Dim dbsReport As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rstSKSF As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
 Dim xlsxPath As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

   Set dbsReport = CurrentDb
   xlsxPath = "I:\Proj\Tr_Rep " & Format(Now(), "mm-dd-yyyy hhmmss AMPM") & ".xlsx"


   'Open a recordset on all records from the SkillSoft Request table that have
   'a Null value in the ReportsTo field.
   strSQL = "SELECT * FROM SKSF_Req WHERE Flag IS NULL"
   Set rstSKSF = dbsReport.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

   'If the recordset is empty, exit.
   If rstSKSF.EOF Then Exit Sub

   With rstSKSF
      Do Until .EOF

      'join report table with SKSF_request table's Rows
      'Create newworksheet for each report joint with SKSF rows
            Set qdf = dbsReport.CreateQueryDef("Training_Report", _
                "SELECT Report.Name, Report.[Employee Role], Report.[Employee Location], Report.[Retails Region], Report.[Asset Title], Report.[Completion Date], Report.[Completion Stat]FROM Report LEFT JOIN SKSF_Req ON Report.[Asset Title] = rstSKSF(SKSF_Req.[Course Name]) WHERE (((Report.[Asset Title]) = rstSKSF([SKSF_RequestForm].[Course Name])) And (rstSKSF((SKSF_Req.Role) Like " * " & [Report].[Employee Role] & " * ")) GROUP BY Report.Name, Report.[Employee Role], Report.[Employee Location], Report.[Retails Region], Report.[Asset Title], Report.[Completion Date], Report.[Completion Stat], Report.[EMP ID]")

            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Training_Report", xlsxPath, True
            DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "Training_Report"


         .Edit
          rstSKSF![Flag] = "Y" 'Set Flag
         .Update
         .MoveNext

      Loop
   End With

   rstSKSF.Close
   dbsReport.Close

   Set rstSKSF = Nothing
   Set dbsReport = Nothing

   Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
   MsgBox "Error #: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Err.Description

   End Sub
```

Comment: what line of code do you get the error on?

Comment: You know you can create a query that has the records from linked tables, and use that as a recordset, if you must?

Comment: I need my main table join my second table one by one. I get error where I am creating worksheet :  Set qdf = dbsReport.CreateQueryDef("Training_Report",....

Comment: `Now()` should be `Now` also.

Comment: @OverMind can you give me an example?

Comment: Is there an issue with doing this in SQL and then using the query in your `TransferSpreadsheet` call?

Comment: @OverMind I'm not sure , but I attached my sample db in this Link here: [SampleDB](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B980etBxqQuzTGxiS1g3eUlLcHc/edit?usp=sharing) please see if you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is the source of your error, but you have double quotes inside your SQL statement (`(SKSF_Req.Role) Like " * " & [Report].[Employee Role] & " * "` that will surely cause the code to fail. Also, you can't refer to a recordset within a SQL statement like that (Would it be possible to include the recordset in the SQL directly instead of iterating over it? It would be much faster)

```
"SELECT Report.Name, Report.[Employee Role], Report.[Employee Location], Report.[Retails Region], Report.[Asset Title], Report.[Completion Date], Report.[Completion Stat]FROM Report LEFT JOIN SKSF_Req ON Report.[Asset Title] = rstSKSF(SKSF_Req.[Course Name]) WHERE (((Report.[Asset Title]) = rstSKSF([SKSF_RequestForm].[Course Name])) And (rstSKSF((SKSF_Req.Role) Like " * " & [Report].[Employee Role] & " * ")) GROUP BY Report.Name, Report.[Employee Role], Report.[Employee Location], Report.[Retails Region], Report.[Asset Title], Report.[Completion Date], Report.[Completion Stat], Report.[EMP ID]"
```

should be more like:

```
"SELECT Report.Name, Report.[Employee Role], Report.[Employee Location]," & _
" Report.[Retails Region], Report.[Asset Title], Report.[Completion Date], " & _
" Report.[Completion Stat] " & _
"FROM Report LEFT JOIN SKSF_Req ON Report.[Asset Title] = '" & rstSKSF![Course Name] & "'" & _
" WHERE (((Report.[Asset Title]) = '" & rstSKSF![Course Name] & "'" & _
" And '" & rstSKSF!Role & "' Like ' * ' & [Report].[Employee Role] & ' * ')) " & _
" GROUP BY Report.Name, Report.[Employee Role], Report.[Employee Location], " & _
" Report.[Retails Region], Report.[Asset Title], Report.[Completion Date], " & _
" Report.[Completion Stat], Report.[EMP ID]"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, NOw I get Run-time error 3085 undefined function 'rstSKSF' in expression and point out this line:            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Training_Reportsheet", xlsxPath, True

Comment: oh I see, it's not a function, you are trying to refer to your recordset. you also should not include values from the recordset in the string that way. Editing my response

Comment: Another thing to be aware of, you will need to escape single quotes if it is possible for a `Course Name` or a `Role` to have the ' character. (something like `Replace(rstSKSF![Course Name],"'","''")`)

Comment: `rstSKSF(SKSF_Req.[Course Name])` doesn't work, first you treat it like a function, second you put it inside the query, but it is not accessible when the query is run. it should be `'" & rstSKSF![Course Name] & "'`, of course being wary of single quotes.

Comment: thank you , i get another error and getting so tired can you help again please? This time run-time error 3296 JOIN expression not supported

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
DAO doesn't take `"' Like ' * ' & [Report].[Employee Role] & ' * '` and I was reading from query and had to change it to real table in s`trSQL = "SELECT * FROM SKSF_Req WHERE Flag IS NULL"` Statement.